# How to arrange Checkboxes in PreferenceActivity in gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-gridlayout

I have found everywhere but couldn't get a right solution.

I have a preference activity, which has a default layout of every element. In mine, there are two *PreferenceCategory* , one has a *ListPreference* and other a number of *CheckBoxPreference*.

I know how to set the custom layout of each element. i.e I have applied the custom checkbox successfully. **But I want to have the checkboxes in 3X3 grid , not in listview.**

here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Location Filter" >
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="-1"
            android:entries="@array/location"
            android:entryValues="@array/locationvalues"
            android:key="locationfilter"
            android:negativeButtonText="@null"
            android:positiveButtonText="@null"
            android:summary="Value"
            android:title="Display results for" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category" 
        >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_one"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 1" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_two"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 2" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_three"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 3" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_four"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 4" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_five"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 5" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_six"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 6" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="key_seven"
            android:layout="@layout/checkboxlayout"
            android:title="Cat 7" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have an image to explain the scenario.
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: I gave you an upvote so you can add an image.

Comment: is this questions solve? how?